# How to implement event dispatching from a Windows Script host to a script

Tags: c++, winapi, com, event-handling, iactivescript

I have a C++ COM (multi-threaded apartment model) application that I build with Visual C++ 2019. I am playing with the COM-based Active Script interfaces and classes. I have a JavaScript ("JScript" really, CLSID `{F414C260-6AC0-11CF-B6D1-00AA00BBBB58}`) Active Script COM object created and set up. Everything works surprisingly well (for something that is falling into obscurity, unfortunately).

Is there an idiomatic approach to registering and calling event listeners where a script can use an API like like https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener and where I can dispatch events from the script host (C++)? To clarify, I am well able to call `IDispatch` interface methods from scripts, I want to call script functions that were passed earlier with such methods to the program, from the program. `GetScriptDispatch` is something else -- it lets me call methods available in the global script namespace, but I need to call functions that I pass to a proxied (from the script) "addEventListener" method.

I depend on this functionality because I want to dispatch events. Basically I want `addEventListener` to be available on certain proxied (e.g. objects added to script namespace with `AddNamedItem`) objects and I need to call event listeners added through calls to that method, when certain events in the C++ application happen.

I have read something about `IConnectionPoint`, and the Active Script documentation briefly mentions "event sinks" a couple of times, without there being examples on how and for what these can be used for. There is also the [`IBindEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/winscript/reference/ibindeventhandler-bindhandler) interface, without much explanation again as to what to use it for.

I understand this is ancient stuff, but I like COM and Active Script interface has several implementations, which to me adds utility.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object that implements events (see `IConnectionPoint`).

After starting the script you can call `AddNamedItem`. The script now knows the interface of you object. If it implements it can register to this events when the state changes to `SCRIPTSTATE_CONNECTED`.

If an event is fired, the script will receive the event and will execute the appropriate code section.

There are old samples:

- Q168214 SAMPLE: MFCAXS (you might find it in the wayback engine)
- And there is a sample here in [code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2830/Macro-Scripting-Language-Support-MFC)
- For ATL samples for Events look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/adding-an-event-atl-tutorial-part-5?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thank you for this! Alright, even if I implement `IConnectionPoint` and related interfaces, what exactly gets me to being able to identify script objects that support `addEventListener`, `dispatchEvent` and `Event` and use these APIs? Can you elaborate on that? Does Active Script magically implement `addEventListener` and/or `dispatchEvent` on any object that is a `IDispatch` and a `IConnectionPoint` (for example)?

Comment: I can't tell you what the Scripting Engine does in detail. Just debug one of the samples I gave to you. I can telll you it works easily.